# Why do Google search console and Google analytics show such drastically different data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm looking through Google Webmaster Tools (GWT) and Google Analytics (GA) to see why organic rankings may have dropped recently. I'm looking at the Search Analytics section on GWT from 1/17/16 - 4/15/16 and I'm using the same date range to look at acquisitions traffic on GA.

GWT is telling me that within that date range I have had 7 total clicks whereas GA is telling me, for the same data range, that I've had 1,245 sessions made of 10,80 users from organic traffic.

Why is there such this large discrepancy between both data sets. How can I know what to trust?

Comment: I think a "click" here means accessing one of your webpages directly from google's search results. I also think "sessions" mean the fact that a user is doing something on your page regardless of how they got there. As for organic, I'm gonna take a hunch that either the report is messed up or you read it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

the question is that are your visitors legeit? Google analytics can keep adding numbers even if the traffic is fake(robots visiting your site)

> Why is there such this large discrepancy between both data sets. How
>   can I know what to trust?

You need both so that you can cross reference your data. Generally this how things work:
**GWT/Console** - In the eyes of the visitors visiting your site(traffic source, Country, browser etc)

**GA** - In the eyes of google visiting your site(sitemap index, crawl errors and many other more data)